# Keeping my object from rolling out of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the tilt function on a phone to control an object to roll left and right. I do not want it roll anything beyond the screen width.

As in the simple illustration below, the dotted lines represent the width of the screen. The 'O' is the object and the Max signs indicate the maximum point the object is allowed to roll to.

Max--------O--------Max

But currently using my code, the object still rolls out of the screen. Also tried testing both height n width and ended up the same result where the object rolls out of the screen. Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
public float speed = 10.0F;
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;

        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime;

        if (!(Mathf.Round(dir.x) > Mathf.Round(Screen.width/2)) || !(Mathf.Round(dir.x) < -Mathf.Round(Screen.width/2)))
        {
            transform.Translate(dir * speed);
        } 
    }



**Updated

public float speed = 10.0F;
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;

        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime;
        //transform.Translate(dir * speed);

        if (transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
        }
        else if (transform.position.x > Screen.width)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Screen.width, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(dir * speed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `transform`? Your object 'O'?

Comment: yes transform is the object.

Comment: I assume that it has some form of coordinate stored, so you should be checking on that (ex. `if (transform.x <0) transform.x = 0; else if(transform.x > Screen.width) transform.x = Screen.Width;`)

Comment: I updated the codes using your suggestion but the results are the same. Do advice in case I understaood you wrong. Tnks.

Comment: Ahum, where is the camera in this?

Comment: Do the position check after you do the translate, or don't do the translate if the position of the object is (or is going to be) out of bounds.

Comment: @Rudolfwm Didn't write a separate script yet. Just attached camera to follow the object on Y-axis.

Comment: Check out this post, there is script to resize a plane to fit an ortho camera if you flip this you can setup your camera boundry

[set plane to fill camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362670/unity-2d-background-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I think thereare several ways you can go about checking the transfomrs position.

first off if you were using a 2d camera you could use a method like

```
leftBounds = Camera.x - (Camera.pixelWidth/2);
```

however because ortho camera angles are not set at any particulare size at x distace from camera they are hard to calculate.

i have seen some instances were coliders on the camera just outside the render rand were placed as camera children

adding a colision mask to only affect the appropriate game object would be best.